# JavaScript - change only SPECIFIC object field value at runtime

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have this JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var triangle = new Object();

  triangle.sideA = 3;
  triangle.sideB = 4;
  triangle.sideC = 5;

  triangle. getArea = function () {
  // Return the area of a triangle using Heron's formula
  var sp = (this.sideA + this.sideB + this.sideC) / 2;
  var calc = sp * (sp - this.sideA) * (sp - this.sideB) * (sp - this.sideC);
  return Math.sqrt( calc );
  };

  alert ("area is: " + triangle.getArea());

  //triangle.sideA = 30;
  //triangle.sideB = 40;
  triangle.sideC = 50;

  alert ("now area is: " + triangle.getArea());

</script>
```

First `alert` call displays the correct value.
Second `alert` call displays *NaN*.

If I uncomment the two commented lines (setting new values also to `sideA` and `sideB`, then the second `alert` call also displays a correct value.

What am I doing / did I understand wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: Well in second scenariio you don't have a triangle. You can't build it out of the 3,4 50 sides.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Comment: `calc` is probably negative. You cannot get the square root from a negative number. The issue has nothing to do with objects in particular.

Comment: Indeed, I was so preoccupied and stuck with JS objects / scope related issues that I simply missed this obvious fact...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you have is trying to calculate the square root of a negative number. I added an extra alert to show what you are doing.

```js
  var triangle = new Object();

  triangle.sideA = 3;
  triangle.sideB = 4;
  triangle.sideC = 5;

  triangle. getArea = function () {
  // Return the area of a triangle using Heron's formula
  var sp = (this.sideA + this.sideB + this.sideC) / 2;
  var calc = sp * (sp - this.sideA) * (sp - this.sideB) * (sp - this.sideC);
     alert( calc);
  return Math.sqrt( calc );
  };

  alert ("area is: " + triangle.getArea());

  //triangle.sideA = 30;
  //triangle.sideB = 40;
  triangle.sideC = 50;

  alert ("now area is: " + triangle.getArea());
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was so absorbed by testing the little stuff I've learned about JS that I completely missed the fact that there can be no such triangle ...

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for `calc` will return a negative number if you set side C to be 50.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt

`Math.sqrt` returns `NaN` for negative arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`calc` results in a negative number "**-382815.5625**".

So `Math.sqrt( calc )` = NaN.

You gave your object `triangle` properties (**sideA = 3**, **sideB = 4**, **sideC = 5**), after that you changed the sideC to **50**, but sideA and sideB remain 3 & 4 respectively. Then we have

`var sp = (3 + 4 + 50) / 2; = 28.5
 var calc = 28.5 * (28.5 - 3) * (28.5 - 4) * (28.5 - 50); = -382815.5625`

Your code works when you uncomment the 2 lines because then the number is not negative.

I suggest you use `console.log()` and the console instead of `alert()` while testing your code, it's much easier to work with.